# How to bake a framework into a static library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, linker

I'm developing a static library **Public.a** that relies on **Secret.framework**. I don't want my project **Client.xcodeproj** to have to link against **Secret.framework** directly; I want **Public.a** to have it 'baked in' so that **Client.xcodeproj** can live in blissful ignorance of its existence.

In other words, I have:

- **Public.a** (links against Secret.framework)
- **Client.xcodeproj** (links against Public.a, and NOT Secret.framework)

How can I do this?

Comment: is Secret.framework always available in runtime?

Comment: The idea is to make it always available by linking it into Public.a